# Rails - Passing data from views to another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm fairly new to rails so any help would be much appreciated.

I have a page where it shows a list of food (each food has its own id). The list of food shown will differ depending on the restaurant selected (queried from db so its dynamic). In this page, users can input the quantity amount for each food that they want.

The following is the controllers and views that i have setup:

- Controllers: Menu and Order Summary
- Views: menu/show.html.erb and order_summary/index.html.erb

I want to display the quantity for each food that the user have entered in the order_summary/index.html.erb.

My question is after the user have entered the quantity inputs, how do i pass the input values together with the food id into the Order Summary controller?

Below is the snippet of the code for the view menu/show.html.erb

```html
<% @menu_appetizer.each do |appetizer| %>
<div class="food-info">
    <div class="food-title"><%= appetizer.name %></div>
    <p class="food-description"><%= appetizer.description %></p>
</div>
<div class="food-price">
    <span class="price">RM<%= appetizer.price %></span>
</div>
<input type="number" min="0" class="quantity-input" data-price="<%=appetizer.price%>" data-food-id="<%=appetizer.id%>">
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'CONTINUE', {:controller => "order_summary", :action => "index"} %>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to make the forms(form_for) with food title and quantity as input tag and submit it to order controller.

OR

you can use AJAX on button click and pass data to order controller.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Would AJAX still be applicable if its loading two different pages? Like from menu/show.html.erb --> [click Continue button] --> order_summary/index.html.erb

Answer (score 0):

The index page is generally used for displaying every item in a given table (or at least a selection). It sounds like you're looking to display a specific order summary, so it would probably be better off going into order_summary/show.html.

This would mean a separate action in your order_summary controller where you get the order summary and give it to the view. If you have your routes set up in the standard way, you get the order summary from either params[:id] or params[:order_summary_id]:

```
def show
  @order_summary = OrderSummary.find(params[:id])
end
```

This allows you to access the @order_summary from your view. Depending on how you've set up your model, that means you could do say:

```
<% @order_summary.items.each do |item| %>
  <div class="food-info">
    <div class="food-title"><%= item.name %></div>
    <p class="food-description"><%= item.description %></p>
  </div>
  <div class="food-price">
    <span class="price">RM<%= item.price %></span>
  </div>
  <input type="number" min="0" class="quantity-input" data-price="<%=appetizer.price%>" data-food-id="<%=appetizer.id%>">
<% end %>
```

Which, assuming you have setup your order summary to have many items, will display the above info.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Comment: No worries hope it helps and makes sense!

Comment: However i dont have a OrderSummary model. Only a Menu model which contains all the food and its details. The purpose of the order_summary/index.html.erb (or as you suggested changing to show.html.erb) is to summarize what the user have selected from the food menu page (menu/show.html.erb) in terms of food choices and quantity.
I need a way to pass the data  (each food id and it's quantity entered by the user) to the OrderSummary controller. Apologies if this is too confusing

Answer (score 0):

You should use AJAX to pass data that can also be good for your page because with AJAX it can get data without loading.